# Alarm like timer functionality in Golang

Tags: go, timer

Is there any way for designing a timer that expires on a specific future time in Golang ? I mean a timer that expires on 2AM (let the current time be 12AM). I know one way is to use,

```
 timer(target_future_time - current_time)
```

but doesn't seem to be an exact way of doing it (may not be accurate on considering the execution time). Can anyone help please?

Comment: What's wrong with `Timer` from package `time`? It does exactly what you need. (Btw. the concept of doing something "exactly at some point in time" doesn't work out well.)

Comment: @Volker this is a production level issue and I better wish to meet that , "exactly at some point in time" as the case is in a distributed environment. Timer was fine otherwise.

Comment: What do you do if the OS clock gets readjusted and skips the "exact moment of time" you wish to execute something? What if the VM is suspended then? What if your laptop sleeps? Just because someone demands that something should happen "exactly then and then" and it has to be on production doesn't make the fundamental problem go away. Esoteric, but what if you schedule something and this instead if time never happens because it was dropped as a negative leap second?

Comment: @Volker Okay, I certainly understand. So it is up to the point that, in practice, "exactly at some point in time" is only nearly possible, right?

Comment: Exactly. And normally business wants things to happen at a certain clock reading which is bound to a timezone and not at some UTC or even TAI ( International Atomic Time) time point. E.g. "Publish this at exactly 9:00 o'clock". Now "9 o'clock" is sometimes one hour later/earlier depending on daylight saving times. And daylight saving times change politically and sometimes on short notice. Just because something seems simple (because as a child you learn to be home at 6 pm sharp) it can be complicated.

Comment: @Volker many thanks for that point. Now it is clear. Thanks.

Comment: On general purpose hardware and operating systems, this is as accurate as you can get. Operating systems alarms also work on intervals (i.e. setitimer), not absolute time, and when they fire your process may still need to be paged in, wait for CPU, etc.

Comment: @JimB thanks for update. Very useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In golang,maybe there are two way create ticker,just like the following:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    //第一种实现方式 
    ticker1 := time.NewTicker(1 * time.Second)
    i := 1
    for c := range ticker1.C {
        i++
        fmt.Println(c.Format("2006/01/02 15:04:05.999999999"))
        if i > 5 {
            ticker1.Stop()
            break
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(time.Now().Format("2006/01/02 15:04:05.999999999"), " 1 Finished.")

    //第二种实现方式 
    i = 1
    ticker2 := time.AfterFunc(1*time.Second, func() {
        i++
        fmt.Println(time.Now().Format("2006/01/02 15:04:05.999999999"))
    })

    for {
        select {
        case <-ticker2.C:
            fmt.Println("nsmei")
        case <-time.After(3 * time.Second):
            if i <= 5 {
                ticker2.Reset(1 * time.Second)
                continue
            }
            goto BRK
        }
    BRK:
        ticker2.Stop()
        break
    }
    fmt.Println(time.Now().Format("2006/01/02 15:04:05.999999999"), " 2 Finished.")
}
```

Output:

```
2016/01/26 16:46:34.261248567
2016/01/26 16:46:35.256381743
2016/01/26 16:46:36.259717152
2016/01/26 16:46:37.260320837
2016/01/26 16:46:38.259312704
2016/01/26 16:46:38.259410752  1 Finished.
2016/01/26 16:46:39.260604274
2016/01/26 16:46:42.261091322
2016/01/26 16:46:45.263136257
2016/01/26 16:46:48.264193517
2016/01/26 16:46:51.265655137
2016/01/26 16:46:53.265722632  2 Finished.
```

**According to the execution,the first is more precise than the second.**

In your case,you can use `time.Time.Sub()` to calculate the duration,and execute once using the second method,the rest using the first method.

I hope these help you!

Comment: thanks for your answer. In short, it seems like you are suggesting to run a ticker to check whether the future target time is met and run it until it does. I think it still have issues with the interval of ticker (may be second, millisecond, nano second or so on), and comparison overheads on considering the precision.

Comment: I have not encountered so precise requirements.

Answer (score 0):

The following code achieves your purpose. All you've to do is call ScheduleAlarm() in the manner shown in the main() function below.

```
package main

import (
    "strings"
    "strconv"
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

// A struct for representing time.
type Time struct {
    Hh int // Hours.
    Mm int // Minutes.
    Ss int // Seconds.
}

func main() {
    /*
    Set the alarm as shown below.
    Time must be specified in 24 hour clock format.
    Also, pass the callback to be called after the alarm is triggered.
    */
    alarm := ScheduleAlarm(Time{23, 28, 0}, func() {
        fmt.Println("alarm received")
    })

    // Do your stuff.
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        fmt.Println(i)
        time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    }

    // Don't forget to call the below line whenever you want to block.
    <-alarm
}

// Call this function to schedule the alarm. The callback will be called after the alarm is triggered.
func ScheduleAlarm(alarmTime Time, callback func() ()) (endRecSignal chan string) {
    endRecSignal = make(chan string)
    go func() {
        timeSplice := strings.Split(time.Now().Format("15:04:05"), ":")
        hh, _ := strconv.Atoi(timeSplice[0])
        mm, _ := strconv.Atoi(timeSplice[1])
        ss, _ := strconv.Atoi(timeSplice[2])

        startAlarm := GetDiffSeconds(Time{hh, mm, ss}, alarmTime)

        // Setting alarm.
        time.AfterFunc(time.Duration(startAlarm) * time.Second, func() {
            callback()
            endRecSignal <- "finished recording"
            close(endRecSignal)
        })
    }()
    return
}

func GetDiffSeconds(fromTime, toTime Time) int {
    fromSec := GetSeconds(fromTime)
    toSec := GetSeconds(toTime)
    diff := toSec - fromSec

    if diff < 0 {
        return diff + 24 * 60 * 60
    } else {
        return diff
    }
}

func GetSeconds(time Time) int {
    return time.Hh * 60 * 60 + time.Mm * 60 + time.Ss
}
```

Hope this helps.